Can ValueObject be independent?
I have in my database table "Spam" with words which are not allowed in user comments. If the user uses any word from the Spam table, their comment is automatically rejected. In this case, is Spam a Value Object? Because it doesn't belong to any entity.
public class Spam : ValueObject
{
    public string Word { get; private set; }


    public Spam(string word)
    {
        Word = word;
    }
}

The service in the Infrastructure project:
public class SpamService(DatabaseContext databaseContext)
{
    private readonly DatabaseContext _databaseContext = databaseContext;

    public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetSpamWords()
    {
        return await _databaseContext.Spam
            .Select(x => x.Word)
            .ToListAsync();
    }
}

I use this service in the command handler to check if the comment is valid.

If your domain model is not concerned with modifying the entries in your spam list, then treating the in memory representation of that information using immutable idioms is perfectly reasonable.
That said, it might make more sense for your entire "spam dictionary" to be treated as a single value object, rather than trying to wrap each individual word in its own instance.

The code works for us, we don't work for the code. -- Mike "GeePaw" Hill.


When you said "in memory," did you mean that I can keep a list of prohibited words in a database and read them into memory as Value Objects if I assume their immutability?
